# Merging CSV files with partly same filename

Tags: csv, batch-file, merge, batch-processing

I have a directory containing aprox. 1500 csv files with measuring data, like level, pressure, volume, etc.
The measuring data is exported every hour for every measurement.
So the generated filenames of Level would be Levelxx.csv, where xx ranges from 00-23
The same method applies for Volume and Pressure and all the other measurements, like volume00.csv - volume23.csv.
I want to merge all 24 files of a given measurement to one, like level-day.csv, volume-day.csv and so on.

The command: "copy /b level*.csv level-day.csv /y" works fine for one set,
but how to do that for many more measurements each having 24 hourly files?
The only common denominator in the filenames is the xx which ranges form 00-23.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply iterate a static list of property names in a FOR loop. Note that multiple word names should be enclosed within quotes:

```
@echo off
for %%A in (
  level
  pressure
  volume
  "multiword name"
   etc.
) do copy /b %%A??.csv %%a-day.csv /y
```

Or you could dynamically discover the names of the properties.

Assuming every property always has a time 00 file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%A in (*00.csv) do (
  set "prop=%%~nA"
  set "prop=!prop:~0,-2!"
  copy /b "!prop!??.csv" "!prop!-day.csv"
)
```

If time 00 might be missing sometimes:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: Delete any existing -day files
delete *-day??.csv 2>nul

for /f "eol=: delims=" %%A in (
  'dir /b /a-d *.csv^|findstr "[^0-9][0-9][0-9]\.csv$"'
) do (
  set "prop=%%~nA"
  set "prop=!prop:~0,-2!"
  if not exist "!prop!-day.csv" copy /b "!prop!??.csv" "!prop!-day.csv"
)
```